# Modifications not taken into account when recompiling linux kernel sources

Tags: compilation, linux-kernel

I want to use the writeprotect mode of the userfaultfd feature, but it is implemented only from Linux 5.11.
I have ubuntu 20 with kernel 5.4 so I installed version 5.11 of Linux from sources, but when I reboot on the installed version, and try to use the writeprotect mode in a c user program the macros (e.g., UFFDIO_WRITEPROTECT) still appear not to be defined. And I verified that userfaultfd is not a module (doing lsmod).

In the other hand, if I make a modification for example in the scheduler just for a test (let's say in kernel/sched/core.c:context_switch) the modification are taken into account because this is in-core, but modifications for user space are not, I'm confused.

The userfaultfd.c file is in the fs/ directory of the kernel.
So please is it something that I'm missing in the compilation process (make menuconfig, make, make modules_install, make) ?

Comment: `in a c user program the macros` So did you include the new linux headers from the program?

Comment: I included the userfaultfd.h library which is modified from 5.4 to 5.11

Answer (score 0):

I was wrongly interpreting the error I had.
The modifications are indeed taken into account when I boot on the newly compiled kernel.

But while searching an understanding of what happens when booting on a compiled kernel, I got this:

- When booting on a kernel compiled from sources, the libraries in /usr/include are not modified on the disk
- If you want to overwrite them by the one modified, you should do this:

  make deb-pkg //from the kernel sources directory
  cd ..
  sudo dpkg -i *.deb

This will install the new kernel and overwrite the headers